# nginx try file, if not found, fallback to rewrite not working (redirection loop)

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have 2 scenarios:

- `/media/cache/test.jpg` or `stylesheet/theme/xxxx.css` is generated by the application. It's not a static file present on the filesystem.
- `/assets/test.jpg` is a static file present on the host

I want both of them to be cached by the browser adding `expires 6M` header.

So I did:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix...;
    internal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

# assets, media
location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
    expires 6M;
    access_log off;

    # try accessing the file directly, and if not found 
    # it means the application has to generate it, 
    # so reroute to the @rewriteapp rule.
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}
```

Problem is nginx detects a loop:

`*194369 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while redirect to named location "@rewriteapp", client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /stylesheet/theme/3441-1484735061.css`

What am I missing please ?

Comment: Regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated in order, so the first block still matches the rewritten URI. You need to place the `location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$)` block **above** the `location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif)$` block.

Comment: Sorry, the block on the production were in the correct order, but not in my example. I've now fixed my example to reflect the exact same thing than on the prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so replacing `try_files $uri @rewriteapp;` by `try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;` seems to fix the problem.